# Find a sequence $(f_n)_n$ convergent in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ doesn't exist for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Construct a sequence $(f_n)_n$ convergent in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ does not exist for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

My thought so far:

I am trying to do this for the unit interval $[0,1]$ and then extending it to all of $\mathbb{R}$, and then $\mathbb{R}^d$. Take the following sequence of subintervals of $[0,1]$
$$[0,1],[0,1/2],[1/2,1],[0,1/3],[1/3,2/3],[2/3,1],[0,1/4],\dots,[3/4,1],\dots$$
Now denote the $n$th interval above by $E_n,$ and let $f_n(x)=1_{E_n}(x).$ Then $$\left(\int_{[0,1]}f_n(x)^{p}\,dx\right)^{1/p}=m(E_n)^{1/p}=\frac{1}{n^p},$$
and hence $f_n\rightarrow 0$ in the $L^p$-norm. However this sequence does not converge pointwise for any $x\in[0,1],$ since it oscillates between $0$ and $1.$

To extend this to $\mathbb{R}$, I take the following partition of the real line
$$\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z,z+1],\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z,z+1/2],\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z+1/2,z+1],\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z,z+1/3],\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z+1/3,z+2/3],\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}[z+2/3,z+1],\dots,$$
which is a replication of the process done before for $[0,1].$ However, I think that in this construction we lose the convergence in the $L^p$-norm, since I believe that we now have, denoting the $n$th set above by $E_n$,
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{E_n}\,dx\right)^{1/p}=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/p},$$
which diverges to infinity

---

Is there any way to save the above argument? If not, can you provide a hint on how to construct such a sequence?

Thank you for your time, and appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Basically, for your argument, you take a function $f \in L^1([0, 1])$, and then you multiply it with indicator functions in a way such that the limit does not exist or a.e. point $x \in [0, 1]$. For this, you took the function $x \mapsto 1$ which is indeed in $L^1([0, 1])$ but which isn't in $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Couldn't you extend the argument by taking a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ instead (e.g. $x \mapsto e^{-|x|}$)?

Comment: I think it is possible to extend your method using a diagonal counting argument, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument. So you have a countable number of intervals and a countable number of $f_n$ per interval. If you want me to explain it in detail, I will make an answer out of it but try this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to extend your idea to $\mathbb{R}$. Define intervals by $$ [-1,0], [0,1], \\ [-2,-\tfrac{3}{2}], [-\tfrac{3}{2},-1], [-1,-\tfrac{1}{2}],\ldots,[1,\tfrac{3}{2}],[\tfrac{3}{2},2],\\ [-3,-\tfrac{8}{3}],[-\tfrac{8}{3},-\tfrac{7}{3}],\ldots$$

If we denote the $n$-th interval by $I_n$, then the Lebesgue measure of $I_n$ tends to zero as $n \to \infty$, and hence $f_n := 1_{I_n}$ converges to $0$ in $L^p$ as $n \to \infty$. Because of the construction of the sequence, we know that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\sharp \{n \in \mathbb{N}; f_n(x)=0\} = \infty \quad  \text{and} \quad \sharp\{n \in \mathbb{N}; f_n(x)=1\} = \infty,$$ and therefore $f_n$ does not converge pointwise.

In $\mathbb{R}^d$ we can consider

$$g_n(x) := f_n(x_1) \exp \left( - \sum_{j=2}^d |x_j| \right), \qquad x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

where $f_n$ is the function from the first part of this answer.

Comment: For $g_n,$ if $x_j\notin [0,1],$ then $g_n(x)=0$ for all $n,$ which would mean that $g_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ for every such $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Is that observation correct, or did I miss a detail in the construction?

Comment: I think the function $g_n(x)=\sum^{d}_{j=1}f_n(x_j)$ for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in\mathbb{R}^d$, does the trick.

Comment: @GabyAlfonso You are right, I forgot that you want to construct $f_n$ such that pointwise convergence fails to hold for any $x$ (and not only for some set of measure $>0$). See my edited answer for a better suggestion but you can also consider the sum, yes.